# Can only send / recieve message once using ISMB Java library

Tags: java, android, nfc, nfc-p2p, acr122

I am using https://code.google.com/p/ismb-snep-java/

I have a problem that I can only send or receive a message once.

I can send a message to the phone, and then I have to unplug the reader
and then plug it again, and then I can repeat the process (send / receive).

**I think there is something is being set on the reader and not being unset.**

If I repeat the process without unplugging it and replugging it, the following error occurs:

```
Get factory
Get terminals
Terminal name: ACS ACR122 0
Available Commands: receive, send and quit
send
card: PC/SC card in ACS ACR122 0, protocol T=1, state OK
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: apdu must be at least 2 bytes long
    at javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU.check(Unknown Source)
    at javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.transmit(Unknown Source)
    at it.ismb.snep.IsmbSnepConnectionTarget.transceive(IsmbSnepConnectionTarget.java:113)
    at it.ismb.snep.IsmbSnepConnectionTarget.sendingProcedure(IsmbSnepConnectionTarget.java:160)
    at it.ismb.snep.NfcReader.<init>(NfcReader.java:76)
    at it.ismb.snep.NfcReader.main(NfcReader.java:39)
Protocol:T=1
Called Procedure to Send data .. TARGET MODE
[DEBUG] {sending   [56 bytes]} 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x33 0xD4 0x8C 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x40 0x01 0xFE 0x0F 0xBB 0xBA 0xA6 0xC9 0x89 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x01 0xFE 0x0F 0xBB 0xBA 0xA6 0xC9 0x89 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0x46 0x66 0x6D 0x01 0x01 0x10 0x03 0x02 0x00 0x01 0x04 0x01 0x96
```

What is the problem ?

```
public NfcReader() {            
     TerminalFactory factory;

     //List all available terminals          
     try {
         System.out.println("Get factory");
         factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
         System.out.println("Get terminals");
         terminals = factory.terminals().list();          
         if (terminals.size() == 0) {
             System.out.println("There are not terminals!");
             terminals = null;      
             System.exit(0);
         }
         else {
             terminal=terminals.get(0);
             System.out.println("Terminal name: "+terminal.getName());
             System.out.println("Available Commands: receive, send and quit");
         }  
    } 
    catch (CardException c) {
        System.out.print(c.getMessage());
        terminals = null;   
        System.exit(0);
    }        
    timer=new Timer();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = "";

    while (line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") == false) {
        try {
            line = in.readLine();
            if(line.compareTo("send")==0){
                setUp();
                n.sendingProcedure();


                try {
                    in.close();                             
                } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();} 
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else{   
                if(line.compareTo("receive")==0){                           
                    setUp();                        
                    n.receivingProcedure();

                    try {
                        in.close();                                 
                    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
                    System.exit(0);                         
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Command unknown!");
                    System.out.println("Supported commands are: send, receive and quit ");
                }   
            }
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}                             
    }

    System.exit(0);


}
```

---

public class IsmbSnepConnectionTarget {

```
    //USEFUL APDU COMMANDS 
    private final static byte TG_GET_DATA = (byte) 0x86;
    private final static byte TG_INIT_AS_TARGET = (byte) 0x8c;
    private final static byte TG_SET_DATA = (byte) 0x8e;
    private final static byte IN_JUMP_FOR_DEP = (byte) 0x56;
    private CardTerminal terminal;
    private CardChannel ch;
    private Card card;
    //  Enable debugMode to print info about the communication
    private boolean debugMode = false;

    //Set debug mode
    public void setDebugMode() {
            debugMode = true;
    }

    //Unset debug mode
    public void unsetDebugMode() {
            debugMode = false;
    }


    /**
     * Initialize SNEP Connection
     *
     * @param t
     *            a valid card terminal
     *
     * @throws IsmbSnepException
     *             if the terminal is incorrect
     */
    public IsmbSnepConnectionTarget(CardTerminal t) throws IsmbSnepException {
        if (t == null) {
                throw new IsmbSnepException("invalid card terminal");
        }
        terminal = t;                
        try {
             if (terminal.isCardPresent()) {                         
                 card = terminal.connect("*");                       
                 System.out.println("card: "+card);
                 ch = card.getBasicChannel();                   
                 System.out.println("Protocol:"+card.getProtocol());   
                 } 
             else {
                 throw new IsmbSnepException("Device not supported, only ACS ACR122 is supported now");
             }
        } catch (CardException e) { throw new IsmbSnepException("problem with connecting to reader");}       
    }

    /**
     * Sends and receives APDUs to and from the controller
     *
     * @param instr
     *            Instruction
     * @param param
     *            Payload to send
     *
     * @return The response payload 
     */
    private byte[] transceive(byte instr, byte[] payload) throws IsmbSnepException {

            if (ch == null) {
                    throw new IsmbSnepException("channel not open");
            }
            int payloadLength = (payload != null) ? payload.length : 0;
            byte[] instruction = { (byte) 0xd4, instr };

            //ACR122 header
            byte[] header = { (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                            (byte) (instruction.length + payloadLength) };

            /* construct the command */
            byte[] cmd = Util.appendToByteArray(header, instruction, 0,
                            instruction.length);
            cmd = Util.appendToByteArray(cmd, payload);

            if (debugMode)
                    Util.debugAPDUs(cmd, null);

            try {
                    CommandAPDU c = new CommandAPDU(cmd);
                    ResponseAPDU r = ch.transmit(c);

                    byte[] ra = r.getBytes();

                    if (debugMode)
                            Util.debugAPDUs(null, ra);

                    /* check whether APDU command was accepted by the Controller */
                    if (r.getSW1() == 0x63 && r.getSW2() == 0x27) {
                            throw new CardException(
                                            "wrong checksum from contactless response");
                    } else if (r.getSW1() == 0x63 && r.getSW2() == 0x7f) {
                            throw new CardException("wrong PN53x command");
                    } else if (r.getSW1() != 0x90 && r.getSW2() != 0x00) {
                            throw new CardException("unknown error");
                    }
                    return Util.subByteArray(ra, 2, ra.length - 4);
            } catch (CardException e) {

                    throw new IsmbSnepException("problem with transmitting data");
            }
    }




    public void sendingProcedure(){
        System.out.println("Called Procedure to Send data .. TARGET MODE");         

        try {   
         //TG_INIT_AS_TARGET
         byte[] targetPayload = {   
                (byte) 0x00,   //MODE
                //(byte) 0x01, //PASSIVE MODE ONLY 
                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, //MIFARE PARAMS 
                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x40, //MIFARE PARAMS
                (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xa6, //FELICA PARAMS 
                (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, //FELICA PARAMS
                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, //FELICA PARAMS
                (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0xba, //NFCID3t
                (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, //NFCID3t  
                (byte) 0x0F, //LEN Gt
                (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0x6D, //LLCP WORD                  
                (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10, //VERSION NUMBER
                (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, //WELL KNOWN SERVICE LIST
                (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x96 //LINK TIMEOUT
             };                 
            transceive(TG_INIT_AS_TARGET, targetPayload);
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}      


        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try { 
             //GETDATA
             transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}    

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try { 
            byte[] targetPayload = { 
                        (byte)0x11, (byte)0x20,};   
            transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
         } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try { 
            byte[] targetPayload = { 
                        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,};   
            transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
         } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
             Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try {                       
            //GETDATA
            transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}    


        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try { 
            byte[] targetPayload = { 
                    (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0x20, //INFO LLCP        
                    (byte) 0x00, //SEQUENCE
                    (byte) 0x10, //VERSION                          
                    (byte) 0x02, //PUT                      
                    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x58, //SNEP LENGTH
                    (byte)0xD2, //NDEF FIRST BYTE
                    (byte)0x24, //TYPE LENGTH
                    (byte)0x31, //PAYLOAD LENGTH
                    //application/com.example.android.beam  
                    (byte)0x61, (byte)0x70, (byte)0x70, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0x69, 
                    (byte)0x63, (byte)0x61, (byte)0x74, (byte)0x69, (byte)0x6F, 
                    (byte)0x6E, (byte)0x2F, (byte)0x63, (byte)0x6F, (byte)0x6D, 
                    (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x78, (byte)0x61, (byte)0x6D, 
                    (byte)0x70, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x61, 
                    (byte)0x6E, (byte)0x64, (byte)0x72, (byte)0x6F, (byte)0x69,
                    (byte)0x64, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x62, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x61, 
                    (byte)0x6D, 
                    //end of application/com.example.android.beam   
                    (byte)0x42,
                    (byte)0x65, (byte)0x61, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x20, //Beam 
                    (byte)0x72,
                    (byte)0x65, (byte)0x63, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x69, (byte)0x76,
                    (byte)0x65, (byte)0x64, (byte)0x20, //received
                    (byte)0x66, (byte)0x72, (byte)0x6F, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x20, //from
                    (byte)0x49, (byte)0x53, (byte)0x4D, (byte)0x42, (byte)0x20, //ISMB
                    (byte)0x53, (byte)0x4E, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x50, (byte)0x20, //SNEP
                    (byte)0x4C, (byte)0x49, (byte)0x42,                     
                    (byte)0x52, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x52,
                    (byte)0x59, (byte)0x3A, (byte)0x0A,
                    (byte)0x0A, //LIBRARY: /n
                    (byte)0x67, (byte)0x6F,
                    (byte)0x6F, (byte)0x64, (byte)0x20, //good
                    (byte)0x6C, (byte)0x75, (byte)0x63,
                    (byte)0x6B, (byte)0x21 //luck!
                    };  
                transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try { 
             //GETDATA
             transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null); //RECEIVED RR
             //[DEBUG] {receiving [8 bytes]} 0xD5 0x87 0x00 0x83 0x44 0x01 0x90 0x00 
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}


        //INVIO DISC
        try { 
            byte[] targetPayload = { 
                        (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x60};  
            transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
         } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
             Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try {   
            //GETDATA
            transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);                  
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }



    public void receivingProcedure(){
        System.out.println("Called new Procedure to receive data .. TARGET MODE");         

        try {
            byte[] targetPayload = { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02,
                    (byte) 0x04,
                    (byte) 0x46, 
                    (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0x6D, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10,                                                                      
                    (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x96              
            };          
             transceive(IN_JUMP_FOR_DEP, targetPayload);
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}      

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try { 
             //GETDATA
             transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}    

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        //WAIT FOR A  Connect request                                        
        while(true){
            try { 
                byte[] targetPayload = { (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, }; 
                transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
            } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

            try { //GETDATA
                byte[]array = transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);
                System.out.println("333333333333");
                if ((byte)array[1]==(byte)0xff){            //RECEIVE SOMETHING SIMILAR TO 0x11 0x20        
                    break;
                }                   
            } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}    

            try {
                System.out.println("444444444444444");
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}               
        }
        //SEND CC - CONNECTION COMPLETE              
        try { 
             byte[] targetPayload = { (byte)0x81, (byte)0x84};  
             transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
        }catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}   

        //WAIT FOR A SNEP REQUEST
        while(true){
            try { 
                byte[] targetPayload = { (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, }; 
                transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
            } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

            try { //GETDATA
                byte[]array = transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);
                if (array.length>=80){                                          
                    System.out.println("Something received: \n"+ Util.byteArrayToAsciiString(array));
                    break;                  
                }
             } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   

             try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}               
        }           

        //SNEP REQUEST RECEIVED
        try { 
            byte[] targetPayload = { (byte)0x83, (byte)0x44,(byte)0x01 }; //Receive Ready   
            transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
         } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try { //GETDATA
            byte[]array = transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);                                        
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}        

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try {                                                      
            byte[] targetPayload = { (byte)0x83, (byte)0x04,(byte)0x01, (byte)0x10, (byte)0x81,     
                        (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00 //LENGTH
                    };  
            transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}        

        //WAIT FOR RR
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try { //GETDATA
            byte[]array = transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);                                        
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try { 
            byte[] targetPayload = { (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, }; 
            transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try { //GETDATA
            byte[]array = transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);                                        
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try {                        
            byte[] targetPayload = { (byte)0x81, (byte)0xC4,(byte)0x00 }; //Disconnected Mode
            transceive(TG_SET_DATA, targetPayload);
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        try { //GETDATA
            byte[]array = transceive(TG_GET_DATA, null);                                        
        } catch (IsmbSnepException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

}

Comment: Maybe you can 'reset' the scanner in some way?

Comment: i tried but sadly no luck ,how can i ask question to specific user ?

Comment: You cannot ask a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with Galaxy S4(5.0.1).

I tried to use old project with NDEF protocol ( https://code.google.com/p/ismb-npp-java/ )

It works fine.

Comment: which one did you use ??

Comment: I opened wiki (https://code.google.com/p/ismb-npp-java/w/list) and did what they write. Then I tried send and receive data many times and all fine(if that can be said, because i didn't see message's text and I can't receive message from PC through Google+ in device)